# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Anonymous Type#1[]' to 'int[]'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, anonymous-types

I have the following scenario in which i am trying to fetch database details using grouping method

```
  //Gets MulitCourseIds from db of selected CourseIds 
        int[] _hasListCourseIds = (from mcd in _db.MultiCourseDetails
                                 where _lstCourseIds.Contains(mcd.CourseId.Value)
                                 group mcd.MultiCourseId by mcd.MultiCourseId into g
                                 select new { multiCourseId = g.Key }).ToArray();
                                   ************  error is occuring here**********

        if (_hasListCourseIds.Count > 0)
        {
            //Checks the count of courseIds from the db and selected courseIds
            foreach (var _multiCourseId in _hasListCourseIds)
            {                  
                var _courseCount = _db.MultiCourseDetails                                       
                                    .Where(x => x.MultiCourseId == _multiCourseId )
                                    .Count();
                if (_courseCount == _lstCourseIds.Count)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

I am getting  error as

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Anonymous Type#1[]' to 'int[]'

Any suggestion to improve the code is also invited..

Comment: if you don't care about the type, use `var` instead of `int[]`

Comment: sorry mate casting is required as I was using it for checking inside loop as shown in the question..

Comment: `g.Key` is already an `int` no? so the anonymous type will also have an `int`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are projecting an `anonymous` type but assigning it to a `int` array. Since you are projecting just one property you don't need an anonymous type here:-

```
  int[] _hasListCourseIds = (from mcd in _db.MultiCourseDetails
                             where _lstCourseIds.Contains(mcd.CourseId.Value)
                             group mcd.MultiCourseId by mcd.MultiCourseId into g
                             select g.Key).ToArray();
```

I assume `MultiCourseId` is `int`.

Comment: `MultiCourseId`  was `nullable int` so I changed `int[]  _hasListCourseIds` to `int?[] _hasListCourseIds`.It would be helpful if you could post how to perform the above scenario `anonymous type` was required..:)

Comment: @ksg - Hey didn't get you - "It would be helpful if you could post how to perform the above scenario". You want to store the anonymous type?